# Puedo almacenar un valor en LocalStorage desde _app.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Tengo un proyecto en Next13 y necesito guardar la IP del usuario para tenerla disponible en todas las paginas de la aplicacion. Para ello en mi `_app.js` tengo dentro de `getInitialProps` lo siguiente:

```
  let uIP;
  try {
    const {
      req,
    } = appContext.ctx;

    const options = {
      timeout: 5000,
    };

    if (req) {
      if (req.headers) {
        uIP = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"];
      } else if (req.connection && req.socket.remoteAddress) {
        uIP = req.socket.remoteAddress;
      } else {
        uIP = await fetch("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", options).then(res => res.json()).then(data => data.ip);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
    uIP = requestIp.getClientIp(appContext.ctx.req);
  }
```

Esto funciona, sin embargo me gustaria que esta obtencion de la IP no se realice cada vez que el usuario acceda a una pagina. Me gustaria guardar la IP en el localStorage, y si esta existe, evitar correr todo este codigo. Si no existe, este codigo debe guardarla en LocalStorage despues de obtenerla.

El problema que tengo es que yo necesito que todas las paginas reciban una prop llamada `uIP`, por lo que entiendo que debo colocarla dentro de `_app.js`.
Al mismo tiempo quiero guardarla en LocalStorage y la funcion `getInitialProps` no puede hacerlo porque corre en el servidor.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Puedes usar cookies ya que puedes acceder a ellos desde el cliente y desde el servidor.

Comment: @Stefan gracias, en la documentación de Next.js dice que las cookies podes leerlas desde un componente del servidor o escribirlas en una acción del servidor o un controlador de ruta. Como aplicaria en mi caso? Yo intente envolver el try/catch en un if con la condicion `if (!cookies().has("uIP"))`. Al finalizar el try/catch hago `cookies().set("uIP", uIP);` y por ultimo, en el else hago `uIP = cookies().get("uIP");` Esto me devuelve el mismo error que si intento usar Local Storage: `Error: Invariant: cookies() expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available.`

Comment: @Stefan cabe aclarar que el error me lo marca en la linea que tiene `cookies().has("uIP")`

Comment: Tu respuesta desde el servidor tendria que retornar una cabecera del tipo `Set-Cookie` ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)).

Comment: @KBeDev finalmente eliminé la llamada de _app.js y utilicé el contexto, que tiene acceso al LS y puede wrappear toda la aplicacion, por lo que todas las paginas acceden al contexto y pueden leer uIP